# Rails: How to update model records from console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to convert values stored in my Rails 3.0 application's database table from pounds to kilograms. This is a one-time task.

Is this something I could do from the console? If so, how?  The values are stored in my weights table in the weight_entry column.

I know it should look something like:

```
Weights.each do |weight|
  weight.weight_entry = weight.weight_entry * 0.45
  weight.save
end
```

I don't know how to initialize the Weights constant though.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Start a console with rails console then type in your command.  Also, if you have followed convention then your model will be Weight and not Weights.

Comment: If `Weight` is a `model` you could call it like `Weight.all.each do |weight|` and then do the loop...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rails c`

```
weights = Weight.all

weights.each do |weight|..
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

rails c

Weight.all.each{ |weight_obj| weight_obj.update_attributes(:weight_entry => (weight_obj.weight_entry * 0.45) )  }